# how can i change color of string in Message Box?

Tags: java, swing

How can i change `color` of `String` in `Message Box`?

```
String patientname="ABC";
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Patient "+patientname+" Already Assigned");
```

In above code i want to change color of `patientname`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use HTML tags and put the content into JLabel, like follows:

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, new JLabel(
    "<html><h2><font color='red'>Hello</font>, world </h2></html>"));
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
JOptionPane option = new JOptionPane();
option.setFont(new Font("Arial"));//Edit this line
option.showMessageDialog(null, "Text Test");
```

**For Specific String**

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Patient <html><font color='red'>"+patientname+"</font></html> Already Assigned");
```